# Scalaz Reader to ReaderT

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

A function which I cannot change returns Scalaz `Reader`,

```
type Action[A] = Reader[Session, A]

def findAccount(s: String): Action[Account] = 
  Reader((session: Session) => Account(s))
```

I want create a new function based on `findAccount(...)` to return `ReaderT[Option, Session, A]` as in

```
type ActionT[A] = ReaderT[Option, Session, A]

def findAccountT(s: String): ActionT[Account] = findAccount(s).map(Option(_))
```

because eventually I want to do this,

```
def findAccBalT(accountNumber: String) = for {
  acc <- findAccountT(accountNumber)
  bal <- findBalanceT(acc)
}  yield bal
```

**How do I proceed? Does it make sense? Thanks**

Full disclosure,

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._        

trait Session {
  def doSomething(): Unit
}

case class Account(number: String) extends AnyVal
case class Amount(value: Int, currency: String) 
case class DBSession() extends Session {
  override def doSomething = println("writing to db")
}

type Action[A] = Reader[Session, A]
type ActionT[A] = ReaderT[Option, Session, A]

def findAccount(s: String): Action[Account] = 
  Reader((session: Session) => Account(s))

def findBalance(account: Account): Action[Amount] = 
  Reader((session: Session) => Amount(333, "S$"))

// failed
def findAccountT(s: String): ActionT[Account] = findAccount(s).map(Option(_))

// failed
def findBalanceT(account: Account): ActionT[Amount] = findBalance(account).map(Option(_))

// failed
def findAccBalT(accountNumber: String) = for {
  acc <- findAccountT(accountNumber)
  bal <- findBalanceT(acc)
}  yield bal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can use `mapK`.

[`Reader[A]`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.3/scalaz_2.11-7.2.3-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.package@Reader[E,A]=scalaz.package.ReaderT[scalaz.Id.Id,E,A]) is a type alias for `ReaderT[Id, A]` and `ReaderT` is an alias for `Kleisli`. [`Id[A]`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.3/scalaz_2.11-7.2.3-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.Id$@Id[+X]=X) is the same as `A`.

In the `Kleisli` ScalaDoc we find [`mapK`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.3/scalaz_2.11-7.2.3-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.Kleisli@mapK[N[_],C](f:M[B]=%3EN[C]):scalaz.Kleisli[N,A,C]) :

```
def mapK[N[_], C](f: (M[B]) => N[C]): Kleisli[N, A, C]
```

Since we know that `Reader[Session, A]` is the same as `Kleisli[Id, Session, A]` we can use `mapK` to go to `Kleisli[Option, Session, A]` :

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type Session = String
type Action[A] = Reader[Session, A]
type ActionT[A] = ReaderT[Option, Session, A]

val action: Action[String] = Reader(s => s)
val actionT: ActionT[String] = action mapK Option.apply
```

Comment: While I was searching for answers, I found out that `Reader` and `ReaderT` are aliases for `Kleisli` with different configurations but I do not have enough brain power to connect the dots. Thanks for pointing these out. I understand mapK signature but do you know where I can find more examples using mapK?

Comment: I don't think there are a lot of examples, but I think the signature is pretty self explanatory: go from a `Kleisli[M, A, B]` to a `Kleisli[N, A, C]` using a function `M[B] => N[C]`. As long as you can define such a function, you can use `mapK`